# Apache Server on my Win 7 not accessible

Tags: apache, windows-7

**Essence:**
   I cannot access my web site which is running on Apache on my Win 7 Pro machine

**Question:**

What security features are available on my ASUS Win 7 Pro machine that will enable me to activate my my Apache Web Server (Apache 2.2.22).

**Enviroment:**
   Two Windows 7 Pro machines and 2 Windown XP machines behind my router.  One of the Windows XP machines is the *main* server.  The newer Asus Windows 7 Pro machine will be the new server.  I have a small developing site on this server now for testing. There is NO firewall active.

**Prior Deviltry:**
   Over the last two weeks, I've been going back and forth between my XP development machine, and this Win 7 Pro server trying to get them talking to each other.

Yesterday, I can finally push/pull files between the two machines.  But in this process -- somehow -- I've lost the ability to visit my website on the new server. (btw, I was able to a week ago ?)

I'm able to use the 127.0.0.1 methos to vist the site with no problems. But to enter the actual URL in the address bar fails with no connection.

I *think* that I have must have done something that forces Win 7 to stop the the Apache httpd from executing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you can ping each machine? Its sounds a network problem, not apache problem.

Comment: Hi PedroMone: I found the answer a few minutes ago: My static IP that I use in my router to direct requests tothe new machine was reset to the original IP for the machine. i.e., 192.168.233 was reset to 192.168.0.12.   SO, my requests were never received by my new server !

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVED this problem by re-checking my 'so-called- static IP on this server and finding it changed I re-instated the static IP of 192.168.0.233

Thank you all and sorry to trouble you. Thanks to Pedrommone for responding

-Mel Smith